# Escape odd number of apostrophes?

Tags: sql

I have a variable in SQL that needs to be able to accept apostrophes. Now, a single apostrophe is easy to escape, but I need to escape any odd amount of apostrophes. How can I essentially detect the amount of apostrophes, determine if it's an odd length, and then multiply it by two for a variable?

```
DECLARE @Variable1 varchar(10)
SET @Variable1 = '123'456'
```

The query returns an error with an odd number length of apostrophes, but doesn't return an error with an even length number of apostrophes.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL (they are not the same)

Comment: SET @Variable1 = '123''456'   Notice the TWO apostrophes in the middle of the string

Comment: Where exactly are you assigning the variable to need to double it? In code one would use a SqlParameter which automatically handles that. Where is your data coming from?

Comment: You need a single quote at the start and another at the end.  Every occurrence of a single quote (apostrophe) within the string needs two adjacent single quotes in the middle of the string —— `'''Apostrophe at start, one '' near the middle (two: ''''), and at the end'''`.  But using placeholders for incoming data should prevent that being a problem.  And there may be a function to do the escaping for you — though which function (if any) will depend on the DBMS you use.

Comment: This is SQL Server. Dale, my input is coming from the user. I'm creating a stored procedure and the stored procedure gets the @Variable1 value from the user. Is there anything I can do to escape an odd number of apostrophes?